# React native, select multiple items from a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a list by using `data.map()` method, but I'm facing a problem that it's only selecting one item but I want it to select multiple items from list. I'm not getting it how to do it.I created that kind list before so user can only select one item from list but I'm struggling to make it select mutliple items. Can someone help?
below is my code

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    isLoading: false,
    isClicked: false,
    selectedIndex: -1,
  });
  const {isClicked, isLoading, selectedIndex} = state;

  const Amenties = ({item, id, callBack}) => {
    const clicked = selectedIndex === id;
    return (
      <View style={styles.amenities}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Image source={item.image} />
          <Text
            style={{
              ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
              color: colors.themeColor,
              marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
            }}>
            {item.amenities}
          </Text>
        </View>
        {clicked ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              callBack(id);
            }}>
            <Image
              source={imagePath.checkboxActive}
              style={{
                width: moderateScale(18),
                height: moderateScaleVertical(18),
                borderRadius: moderateScale(18 / 2),
              }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              callBack(id);
            }}
            style={{
              width: moderateScale(18),
              height: moderateScaleVertical(18),
              backgroundColor: colors.blackOpacity15,
              borderRadius: moderateScale(18 / 2),
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

data is

```
const Top_Amenities = [
    {
      id: 1,
      amenities: 'Wifi',
      image: imagePath.wifiIcon,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      amenities: 'Air Conditioner',
      image: imagePath.airConditionerIcon,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      amenities: 'Printer',
      image: imagePath.printerIcon,
    },
]
```

mapped data

```
  {Other_Amenities.map((data, id) => (
            <Amenties
              item={data}
              id={data.id.toString()}
              callBack={(id) => setState({selectedIndex: id})}
            />
          ))}
```

can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need store id's of list in a array, you will need maintain a index state for each selected list item, set the index state to default 0.
Full updated Code

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

function AddAmenties({navigation}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isLoading: false,
    isClicked: false,
    selectedIndex: [],
    index: 0,
  });
  const {isClicked, isLoading, selectedIndex, index} = state;
  
  const Amenties = ({item, id, callBack}) => {
    var color = "grey"
    if(selectedIndex[1] && selectedIndex.includes(id)){
      color ="blue"
    } else if(selectedIndex[0] === id){
      color = "blue"
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.amenities}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text
            style={{
           
             
              marginLeft: 16,
            }}>
            {item.amenities}
          </Text>
        </View>
        { (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              callBack(id);
            }}
            style={{
              width: 18,
              height: 18,
              backgroundColor:color,
              borderRadius: 18/2,
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const Top_Amenities = [
    {
      id: 1,
      amenities: 'Wifi',
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      amenities: 'Air Conditioner',
   
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      amenities: 'Printer',
   
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      amenities: 'Food',
     
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      amenities: 'Coffee',
    
    },
  ];

 
  const selectedItem = (id) => {
    
    if (selectedIndex == 0) {
      setState({selectedIndex:[ id], index: 1});
     
    } else {
      //alert(selectedIndex)
      if(selectedIndex.includes(id) === false){
        setState({selectedIndex: [...selectedIndex, id], index: index + 1});
      
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView
        style={{
          marginTop: 33,
          marginHorizontal: 16,
        }}>
        <Text>
         Top Amenities
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Top_Amenities.map((data, id) => (
            <Amenties
              item={data}
              id={data.id.toString()}
              callBack={(id) => {
                selectedItem(id);
                console.log(selectedIndex);
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
      
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "grey",
    marginVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 23,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  amenities: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginVertical: 12,
  },
});
export default AddAmenties;
```

Comment: `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.` getting that error

Comment: this happens when the state object is undefined, check if selectedIndexes is getting the intial value.

Comment: wait, let me modify i think i know what is causing issue

Comment: callback is called when you click on the item right

Comment: yup call back is called

Comment: can you check, if id passed on selectedIndexes on if condition, add console.log(this.state.selectedIndexes) to check if it;s not null

Comment: Okk wait i will check

Comment: `  6
[Fri Jan 22 2021 11:38:20.681]  LOG      ["6", "4"]
[Fri Jan 22 2021 11:38:23.363]  LOG      ["6", "4", "3"]` that's the log I got

Comment: so it is getting id's of list items you have selected, you can perform some logic based on these id's, just add an addtional conditional to check the same id is not selected multiple times inside, i.e.if ( selectedIndexes..includes(id) == false){ then update state}

Comment: yup it's getting id's but nothing is happening in screen wait let me add htis code to snack.expo

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@s.kanwarjeet/tactless-almond here check it

Comment: I updated code , kindly check it is working. thanks